# MFC app: How can I can register my program in Add or Remove Programs (ARP)?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I need to register my uninstaller (which is the same .exe) in ARP. Thank's

Comment: Yah but I cant find , I have my own setup.exe , and  I start to get [such warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756937.aspx) in win 7 there is one way to don't get warnings from PCA, that  manually change manifest file of application and add it as resource , but for some reasons I decide that it is not very good way , and want to register my app in ARP , but I cant find how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN:

- [Chapter 2. Install/Uninstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954376.aspx)
- [Uninstall Registry Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The question is in proper use of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` registry key and creating your own entry there.